# Set jQuery slider value dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, slider

How can I set slider value dynamically? 
Here is my current code:

```
 $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 1,
  max:61,

  step: 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {

    var val = ui.value;
   if(val > 10){

     ui.value = ui.value + 3;

  //   $(this).slider('option','max',500);


}
```

And after that this value change only once time (value bounce from 10 to 13 and to 14,15,16... after) but i need 10,13,16,19,etc.
what am i doing wrond?
When I try ui.value = ui.value*ui.value it works excellent (121, 144, 169, 196, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Haven't you forget to close your if statement whith "}" ?

Edit : 
Have you tried something like this :

```
$("#slider").slider('value',50);
```

Comment: No, i've just cut part of code. 
And when I place ui.value = ui.value * ui.value instead of ui.value = ui.value + 3; it give me (121, 144, 169, 196, etc.) Dunno why ui.value + 3 won't work...

Answer (score 1):

The way Pak suggested will recall the slider constructor, which will not be smooth.

The correct way, according to [jQuery UI Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) , is:

```
$("#slider").slider('option','value',50);
```